# How to view only a single line from multiple line chart diagram in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel

How to view only a single line from multiple line chart diagram in Excel.

Example: As shown in the image below, I'm having 3 separate lines, one for each user. I want to see each line separately (as shown in the expected graph) to analyze each user statistics dynamically, instead of seeing all users statistics in one graph (current graph)

[image]
http://s5.postimg.org/6fgxki85j/excel.jpg

Comment: Have you tried using pivot chart? There you can change the data more flexibly.

Comment: i tried, but no use

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many ways to accomplish this -  it just depends on how much flexibility you want to end up with.  Here's one very simple approach to start with:

1. Choose a cell that will allow you to choose your desired user - Maybe *B8*.  Select that cell, then select *Data-->Data Tools-->Data Validation --> Data Validation-->Settings-->Allow-->List*  Under source, enter `$B$1:$D$1`.  This will restrict *B8* to only the names in your column headers
2. Now create a fourth column in your table.  E1 could read "Chosen User."
   E2 would have a formula like `=index(b2:d2,1,match($b$8, $B$1:$D$1))`  Fill this formula down to E7.
3. Plot Column A against Column E.  To change which line is displayed, click on the dropdown in *B8* and choose someone else.

Comment: Thanks Adam for the solution. It worked, but I'm getting incorrect graphs when there are too many columns and rows in the table. Example: When I select Crown from the drop down, Andy graph is displaying, and change of selection from drop down also freezing out sometimes.

Comment: I have used this technique to pull a half dozen curves from a half dozen data sets, each of which has ~400 rows and 60 columns (Excel 2007).  I can't think of why it wouldn't work for you in this simple an example.